# Database Exception: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'position' in 'order clause'

Tags: craft3, database, error

I deployed the project from the git repository on hosting. When trying to open the homepage I get the following error:

```
Database Exception
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'position' in 'order clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`fieldLayoutId`, `elements`.`uid`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_sites`.`slug`, `elements_sites`.`siteId`, `elements_sites`.`enabled` AS `enabledForSite`, `elements_sites`.`uri`, `categories`.`groupId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM `elements` `elements`
INNER JOIN `categories` `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON (`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (`content`.`siteId` = `elements_sites`.`siteId`)
LEFT JOIN `structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM `structures`
WHERE (`id` = `structureelements`.`structureId`) AND (`dateDeleted` IS NULL)))
WHERE (`elements_sites`.`siteId`='1') AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (`elements`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`structureelements`.`level`='2') AND (`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `position`) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `categories` `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId`
LEFT JOIN `structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `subquery`.`elementsId`) AND (`structureelements`.`structureId` = `subquery`.`structureId`)
ORDER BY `position`
```

But the admin page opens without errors.
And when I run a project on a local machine, there is no such error.
What can i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Command `./craft migrate/all` fixed this issue.

Comment: Had the same issue with a different plugin. the migrate/all fixed the issue. Wonderful <3